# Is density of a material related to penetration?

Tags: mass, density

Theoretical question. If you have a standard projectile with mass 1 and velocity 1 and fired it at different materials would the penetration be related to the density of the material? I'm not trying to find how deep it would pentrate just the relativity. so if I fired it at plaster with density "2" then fired it at say conrete with density "4" would it penetrate twice as far into the plaster?

Comment: *"mass 1"*, *"velocity 1"* and *"density 2"* are not proper masses, velocities or densities, respectively (the units are missing). Are you just asking whether projectiles penetrate deeper into less dense materials, all other things being equal? (Then I think the penetration relies crucially on the material structure, not on its density)

Comment: Yes to the second part. and that is what I am afraid of. I'm trying to make a simple shooting competition game and want to take into effect material penetration but I can't really test the penetration for all the materials I want to use but I was hoping I could just use their density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

[A decent approximation of impact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_depth) was found by Isaac Newton. Simply put, it is
$$D=L\frac{A}{B}$$
where $D$ is depth, $L$ is the length of the projectile, $A$ is the density of the projectile and $B$ is the density of the object being impacted. Velocity doesn't play into it.

So double the density of the impacted object and the impact depth will be *decreased* by a factor of two. Note that this is only a basic approximation, though.

Comment: Thank you very much! I only need an approximate for what I am doing. Awesome defined and quick answer!

Comment: @power5000 I'm glad it helped. You can accept the answer with a check mark if it fully solved your problem, although you can wait for other answers if you want. Accepting an answer can be undone, but it does have the downside of discouraging other potentially useful answer.