# Calculating penetration given mass and velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, material-science, collision, projectile

Long story short, I'm trying to design a bullet for a story I'm writing, and trying to work out the math for it myself. The best source I could find was this: http://panoptesv.com/RPGs/Equipment/Weapons/Projectile_physics.php

I tried to follow the equations there, but I’m pretty sure I did something wrong because I ended up with a final maximum penetration against steel of well over a meter. I figured I should take this to the experts since I'm so handily messing this up. Given the below information regarding the bullet and target, what is the maximum penetration of the round?

Mass: 12.3 grams

Velocity (muzzle): 900 m/s

Density: 19.3g/cm^3 (Amorphous Tungsten Alloy, basically tungsten with the self-sharpening properties of depleted uranium)

Height: 56mm (50mm straight, 6mm tapered to point)

Width: 3.6mm (7.2mm including back fins)

Target: High-Carbon steel (Think AR500, the best density information I could find was around 7.84g/cm^3)

Fairly sure I don’t have to specify this, but I might as well for completion’s sake. Please show your work, as I’d love to have a reference to work off if (when) I need to do the math for another projectile

Edit: Adding previous work done. Also, I redid the work and got a different answer, 61.76cm. It still seems a little extreme for this to go through two feet of steel, though, so I suspect this is still wrong. Work is based off equations and rules found in source.

$X_m = x_c \cdot  \log \bigg(1 + \dfrac{v_0^2} { v_{thr}^2}\bigg)$

$X_m$ = Pen distance, $x_c$ = characteristic length?, $v_0 $ = velocity, $v_{thr}$ = threshold speed

$v_0 = 900\;\;ms^{-1}$

$\dfrac12v_{thr}^2 = \dfrac{y_c}{(c_d \cdot p_t)}$

$y_c$ = cavity strength = pressure, $c_d$ = coefficient of drag (around 1 for solid targets), $p_t$ = density of target

$c_d = 1$

$p_t = 7.84 \;g\cdot cm^{-3}$

$Y_c = \dfrac FA$

$F =$ force, $A =$ area

$A = 10.18\;mm^2$ (area of circle with same diameter as projectile)

$F = m \cdot a$

$m =$ mass, $a =$ accelleration

$m = 12.3 \;g$

$a = 900\; m\cdot s^{-2}$

$F = 12.3\; g \cdot (900\;m/s^2) = 11.07 Newtons$

$Y_c = \dfrac{11.07\;N }{ 10.18\;\;mm^2 }= 1.0874\; MPa$

$\dfrac12v_{thr}^2 = \dfrac{1.0874 \;MPa}{ (1 \cdot 7.84 \;g/cm^3)} = 138.7\; m^2/s^2$

$v_{thr} =\sqrt{138.7\;\;m^2/s^2 \cdot 2} = 16.655\;m/s$

$x_c = \dfrac mA\cdot\dfrac 1{(c_d ρ_t)}$

$x_c = \dfrac{12.3\;g}{ 10.18\;\;mm^2}\cdot \dfrac1{(1 \cdot 7.84\;\;g/cm^3)} = 15.41\;\;cm$

$X_m = 15.41cm \cdot \log \bigg(1 + \big[\dfrac{(900\;\;m/s)^2}{ (16.655\;\;m/s)^2}\big]\bigg) = 61.76\;\;cm$

Max penetration  is $61.76\;\;cm$

Comment: could you show us your earlier working ? maybe we could find the problem in it.

Comment: @The Integrator I can attempt to, but it'll take a bit as I'm at work, and I need to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: @TheIntegrator We *specifically* [discourage people from posting images of work](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10260/should-i-edit-question-to-format-equation-linked-as-image-in-mathjax) as you suggest.  It is generally hard to read and can't be searched properly.  For equations and maths the site standard is [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @StephenG i didnt know mathjax was a thing in PSE as well, apologies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is density of a material related to penetration?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175364)

Comment: @The Integrator Just added previous work. Ended up with a different answer than I got last night, but pretty sure it's still wrong. No unit conversion work because I used wolfram a lot, and I'll be damned if I'm doing that by hand on a phone. Also, formatting isn't easy on mobile, so please forgive the crappy layout

Comment: There seems to be some conversion of units needed , apart from that as Bob van de Voort pointed out there seems to be something wrong with $y_c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So looks like your $Yc$ is wrong, it's the cavity strength, as said on the website approximately 3 times the yield strength, AR400 steel has an approximately yield strength of 1.07 GPa. If I then calculate using SI unit I get the following $v_{thr} = \sqrt{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 1.07E9 / 7840} \approx 905 m/s$.

Now if I plug this into your final equation I get the following:
$Xm = 15.41 \cdot ln(1 + (900/905)^2) \approx 10.6 cm$ 
On the website it also say to use ln and not log (log is usually log10 and ln usually loge)

That seems quite realistic to me.

So to get the yield strength you google it and for the cavity strength you multiply it by 3, the units you use should be Pa and $kg/m^3$ for the density and strength as these are SI units and this way the units will make out to be meters/second.

**Edit:** AR500 has a yield strength of around 1.4 GPa, that would make around 8.7 cm instead

Comment: Indeed, that is way more realistic than what I had. I must have missed the yield strength bit when I went through the first time. Thanks Bob

Comment: No worries these things can happen especially if you're not from the field ;) Glad to have been able to help you